# How do you edit records from a VBA form that you want to interactively select?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, editing

I have a set of ComboBox's in an MS Access 2003 DB that are all bound to fields in a single table.  However, the data that they allow you to select doesn't come from that table and instead comes from various other tables.  This works fine for the record creation story but now I want to be able to edit the record retroactively.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to refill the form elements without writing a bunch of custom code.

My initial inclination is to provide a combo box that limits your choices to record IDs and then do a custom query and use that to set the selected values in all of different form elements.  However, I feel like I should be able to do something as simple as `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , , ID` and the form should repopulate just fine.  I'm not opposed to doing the busy work but I'm sure I'm just missing something in my relatively puny knowledge of VBA and Access.

Comment: This question is confusing, if you have a standard form with standard combos there is nothing to do here, it should just work.

Comment: Are you trying to update the items in each combo box because they changed since the form openned?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the mix, I would offer two approaches, one recommended, the other not.

Approach 1: If you've bound your form to the whole data table (this is the non-recommended approach), you can use the combo box wizard to navigate to the requested record, but I wouldn't recommend it in recent versions of Access:

a. it doesn't allow you to properly name the combo box before it creates code.

b. the code is just WRONG.

Here's the code I just produced in my test database:

```
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
rs.FindFirst "[InventoryID] = " & Str(Nz(Me![Combo2], 0))
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

This is wrong in so many ways it's just remarkable. This is what the code should be:

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
  .FindFirst "[ID]=" & Me!cmbMyComboBox
  If Not .NoMatch Then
     If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
     Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
  Else
     MsgBox "Not Found!"
  End If
End With
```

There is no need to clone the form's recordset when the RecordsetClone already exists.

There is no reason to use an object variable when you can just directly use the pre-existing object.

There needs to be a check for a dirty record before departing the record because if you don't force the save, errors in the save process can lead to lost data.

But the better approach is this:

Approach 2: Use the combo box to change the form's underlying recordsource.

The AfterUpdate event of your combo box would look something like this:

```
If Not IsNull(Me!cmbMyComboBox) Then
   Me.Recordsource = Me.Recordsource & " WHERE [ID]=" & Me!cmbMyComboBox
End If
```

Now, this only works the first time, as on the second resetting of the Recordsource, you end up with two WHERE clauses, which is not good. There are two approaches:

a. assuming that the form opens without a WHERE clause, store the opening recordsource value in a module-level variable in the form's OnLoad event:

```
   Private Sub Form_Load()
     strRecordsource = Left(Me.Recordsource,Len(Me.Recordsource)-1)
   End Sub
```

And at the module level, define strRecordsource accordingly:

```
   Dim strRecordsource As String
```

Then in the combo box's AfterUpdate event, you have this instead:

```
   Me.Recordsource = strRecordsource & " WHERE [ID]=" & Me!cmbMyComboBox
```

Now, if your form opens with a WHERE clause already defined, it gets more complicated, but I'll not go into that and leave it as an exercise to the reader what the best approach might be.

Comment: Found a minor typo. I think the "rs.FindFirst..." line after the "With Me.RecordsetClone" in your second example should read ".FindFirst...".

Comment: Oh, and +1. Not being an Access guru, I didn't think to just modify the Recordsource directly. Much more elegant that a DoCmd, I think. Maybe it's just me and the fact I don't really do Access programming, but resorting to DoCmd usually feels like a hack to me (i.e. usually there is a better way).

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you've already set up the row sources for each combo box. So long as you haven't limited the combo box to that list; it should display what you have stored in that column.

However, if your Combo Box changes its list for each row you can do something like this in the record's OnCurrent event or the field's GotFocus event:

```
Me.combo_box_name.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question, I think I see what you are trying to achieve. You're on the right track with `GotoRecord`, although I would probably use `OpenForm` in this case, because it has a `WhereCondition` property that allows you to use SQL to specify exactly what record to open. It sounds like you want to implement a "jump to record" type functionality in your form, where the user selects a record ID from a list and the form changes to display the selected record.

One possibility is to switch to the new record each time the user selects an item in the ComboBox. You can handle this in the ComboBox's `Click` event.

I'll use a simple example: suppose you have a `Students` table, and a `StudentForm` for viewing/editing records in the `Students` table. The `StudentForm` has a ComboBox `cboStudentID` that is bound to the `Students.ID` column via it's `RowSource` property. When you select a student ID in the ComboBox, the `StudentsForm` will switch to display the corresponding student record.

In the `Click` event handler for the ComboBox, you can code this "jump to record" functionality with something like the following:

```
Private Sub cboStudentID_Click() 
    Dim recordID As Long
    'The ItemData property will return the value of the bound'
    'column at the specified index.'
    recordID = cboStudentID.ItemData(cboStudentID.ListIndex)
    'Jump to the record. This assumes we want to use the same form.'
    'You can change the form name if you want to open a different form when'
    'the user selects an ID from the ComboBox.'
    DoCmd.OpenForm "StudentForm", WhereCondition:="Student.ID=" & recordID
End Sub
```

As David W. Fenton points out in the comments, you can shorten the following line:

```
recordID = cboStudentID.ItemData(cboStudentID.ListIndex)
```

to this:

```
recordID = Me!cboStudentID
```

or just:

```
recordID = cboStudentID
```

since the default value of the ComboBox in this case will be the value of the bound column at the current `ListIndex`. In this case, you could just remove `recordID` altogether and code the `Click` event as follows:

```
Private Sub cboStudentID_Click() 
    DoCmd.OpenForm "StudentForm", WhereCondition:="Student.ID=" & cboStudentID
End Sub
```

Comment: If the ID column is the bound column (which is independent of whether or not the combo box is bound, i.e., has a ControlSource), then the default value of the combo box is the ID and there's no need to use ItemData. If you need something other than the bound column, ItemData is just the ticket.

Comment: Thanks, David. I've edited my answer to reflect the fact that they are equivalent in this case.